# What is suitable format to present a Psuedo Code in academic paper?

Tags: journals, formatting

I'm going to include my algorithm as a pseudo-code in a double-column paper format.

However, since lines of my pseudo-code are long I don't know if is it suitable to use the width of both columns to demonstrate algorithm or not? I want to know are there any common rules for this?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the journal's author guidelines. If no specifics are stated, you can often add the pseudo-code like a figure in your text (just labeled with Algorithm 1 instead of Figure 1).

Comment: In addition, the publisher may use the set of parameters (indentations, linebreaks and line numbers, font size) to adjust the formatting of the code to match the width of a column.  The publisher equally may decide that the pseudocode spans across two columns while the text of the publication is set in two columns (like as there are figures for single column [e.g., 8.85 cm], part-page width [e.g., 12 cm] or full-page width [e.g., 18 cm]).